# No way to test apple signin popup on localhost?

Tags: apple-sign-in

As far I can tell there's no way to test the apple signin popup when developing locally because Apple will not postmessage the user data back to localhost. How am I supposed to develop locally? Google signin doesn't have a similar requirement.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe to late, but you can use ngrok to forward a temporary public url to your localhost.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is too late to help you, but I wrote up a blog post about how to work around this. I’ve also linked to a script that simplifies the whole process.

Essentially you create a non localhost address and set a hosts entry to it. You also need to trust your SSL cert to make it seamless.

You can read it here: https://goforgoldman.com/posts/2023-local-apple-signin/